# How to resize an image in GraphViz

Tags: python, graphviz

I try to  resize an image in GraphViz - is too big

```
 image="image/concave.PNG"
```

the output:

[image: img]

this is my code:

```
import graphviz

dot = graphviz.Digraph(comment='Example Graph')
dot.node('A', 'Node A',color='#ff000042', shape='box', style='filled', fillcolor='#ff000042',
         height="0.05pt", width="0.05pt", image="image/concave.PNG", imagepos="tc",
         labelloc="b", resize="0.05pt")
dot.node('B', 'Node B')
dot.edge('A', 'B')

# render the graph to a PNG file
dot.render('example_graph', format='png')
```

```
import graphviz

dot = graphviz.Digraph(comment='Example Graph')
dot.node('A', 'Node A',color='#ff000042', shape='box', style='filled', fillcolor='#ff000042',
         height="0.05pt", width="0.05pt", image="image/concave.PNG", imagepos="tc",
         labelloc="b", resize="0.05pt")
dot.node('B', 'Node B')
dot.edge('A', 'B')

# render the graph to a PNG file
dot.render('example_graph', format='png')
```

Answer (score 0):

set **fixedsize=true** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fixedsize/) to explicitly set the node size to designated **height** & **width**
and **imagescale=true** to (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/imagescale/) to scale the image to that **height** & **width**